# Is it possible to automatically mount a hot-swappable drive when it is turned on?

Tags: linux, mount, ubuntu-12.04, fstab

In my PC, I have a hot-swap drive. Usually I keep it off to save power. I only really use it when accessing from another PC on the network. Is it possible to configure /etc/fstab to mount this drive when I turn it on (without having to shake the mouse, open file manager and click the drive to have it mounted?

Currently, I have:

```
UUID=a869e5ca-7d3b-4d64-91e2-eadbecd8c9e5 /media/i-TVShows ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,auto,user,uhelper=udisks 0 0
```

in my /etc/fstab file but it doesn't seem to do the trick. I want the drive to be user-mountable, on power on, with RW access, and I'm thinking of adding 'nofail'...this is my first time writing to the fstab file, and a lot of the parameters I took from the output of 'mount' so feel free to correct any oddness you find.

Thanks